# Android application for Ask Ubuntu or Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Is there any official or recommended Android application for Ask Ubuntu or Stack Overflow?
Features wanted:

- ask/answer/comment questions
- view user profile
- notification about reputation changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently an Android application for browsing StackExchange sites, so including Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow, is StackAnywhere.

However, since StackExchange APIs does not support login or actions, it's useful only for searching and browsing; it have also a nice widget.

My opinion: I prefer to use the mobile version of Ask Ubuntu official site.

Links:

- [StackAnywhere on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rectangularsoftware.stackanywhere)
- [StackAnywhere Website](http://rectangularsoftware.com/stackanywhere/)

Comment: Tried DroidStack (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.droidstack), StackRemote (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android) and StackAnywhere. None of them meets all the requirements. Thus I came to your proposed "solution" to use the official site.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [stackmobile.com](http://stackmobile.com/) ?

More info [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stack-mobile-view-stack-exchange-sites-on-your-smart-phone-or-tablet).

Comment: stackmobile.com will definitely help you out.  Since there's no current android app dedicated for those.